# How to categorize (lookup) brands with spelling mistakes

Tags: r, python, text-mining

I have a dataset with around 4 million rows. The data has only column which contains around 50000 unique brand names (e.g. IBM, Google, Adobe, Microsoft etc.). 
I also have a lookup table which contains unique numbers associated to each of these brands. So for example, IBM is assigned number 17, Google is assigned number 22 etc. 
The task is to assign these numbers to respective brands in the dataset. In more simple words, it is `vlookup` in MS Excel. But, the problem I am facing here is that the brand names in the dataset have spelling mistakes! So I cannot do a simple lookup here.

Since the data is quite large, I am willing to perform this task in R or Python.

Comment: I think this question should be migrated to SO, because it asks for a python or R solution.

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: @RHA, this will be off topic on [SO] because it lacks a reproducible example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R / Python without a reproducible example.

Comment: @gung You are right off course, but I still think it should be migrated. Then we can ask the OP for a reproducible example. In essence, this question can be good.

Comment: @RHA I actually think that this question could be edited to be on-topic on CV, if the coding element was de-emphasised and more focus was put on designing a *strategy* for this task. So it should be for the post author to decide what they are happier with and edit accordingly. (Moreover, note that the post should not be migrated to SO until it is suitable for SO! The procedure is - sensibly - always to make sure the question is appropriate for migration, before the migration occurs.)

Comment: @Silverfish An edit removing the coding element should be rejected because it "clearly conflicts with autors' intent".

Comment: See [this post on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620166/method-to-classify-misspelled-words-in-groups-according-to-the-right-word) for an R-solution...

Comment: @RHA As I said, *it should be for the post author to decide what they are happier with and edit accordingly*. I'm not suggesting anyone else should edit on their behalf (nor can I see such an attempt in the edit history). The answers that have been posted so far are suitable for a CV question but not an SO one. In its current form the question is not suitable for SO so can't be migrated there (the rules on migration require a Q to be suitable before, not after). This question could be a good SO question or a good CV question but at the moment it falls into a bit of a grey area between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know that *every* name in the data has a corresponding correctly spelled name in the lookup table? In that case, you can choose the correct spelling by minimizing Levenshtein distance. Otherwise, you need to get an estimate of your number of non-matching words and decide what to do about them first.

Comment: Levenshtein distance is one metric. It its computationally intractable with large sets of data. Other options include Jaccard, Dice, Hamming, and so on....there are literally dozens of distance metrics. Here's a link to a workshop on them... http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W06-1101

Answer (score 2):

Kodiologist has good advice in turns of checking some distance metric such as Levenshtein distance. Keep in mind though that in general, this problem can get extremely difficult, and you may only match a subset of your data. Issues:

- Different names, spelling, etc...

  - IBM may be recorded as "IBM," "International Business Machines," or even "Intl Business Machines." (In my experience, it's rather shocking the number of different ways the same thing can be written...)
  - Companies may or may not be recorded with suffixes: LLC, Corp., etc...
- Hierarchical ownership, different divisions, changing corporate structure:

  - Nest was purchased by Google, which in turn is now a division of [Alphabet Inc.](https://www.google.com/finance?cid=304466804484872).
  - Depending on what you want to do, you may or may not want results aggregated at the top, ownership level.
  - [Huge databases exist](http://www.corporateaffiliations.com/) of who owns whom. They probably aren't cheap.